# How does .vimrc set its own filetype?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

In response to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/582573/is-there-a-simple-setting-that-make-vim-find-filetype-more-smart/582579#582579) on SuperUser, I wrote a small vimscript that will detect the filetype of a symbolic link and change the syntax highlighting:

> au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | silent! execute (':set filetype='.matchstr(resolve(@%),'.[^.]*$')[1:]) | endif

So if I open a symbolic link with no extension, it will look at the extension of the file it points to.

It works, but an unintended consequence is that now the syntax highlighting of my `.vimrc` file is gone. By default, my .vimrc file has vim syntax highlighting (`:echo &syntax` returns `vim`).

But when I add the above line, `:echo &syntax` returns `vimrc` (an invalid type).

I don't know why this is happening. Shouldn't `&syntax==''` evaluate to false, and thus keep `&syntax==vim`? I suspect that my code is executing before the syntax highlighting is set to `vim`. But how (and when) exactly *is* the syntax highlighting set to `vim` for `.vimrc`? Additionally, how can I make my script behave the way it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Vim's runtime area for `filetype.vim`.  You can bring it up in vim with:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim
```

In my version, it looks like this line does the trick:

```
" Vim script
au BufNewFile,BufRead *vimrc*           call s:StarSetf('vim')
```

Perhaps you want to put your `autocmd` in `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim`.  I believe this will cause it to be registered after the system ones, and then `&syntax` should be set up correctly.

Comment: I was simply answering your question--how .vimrc's filetype gets set.  If that's not your question, perhaps you should edit it or reword it.  I suspect your autocmd runs first, so yes, the syntax is nil.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood--this does answer the first part of my question.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think you need to put your autocmd in `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim`, so it'll get called after the ones in the Vim runtime.

Comment: Thanks--this may work (haven't tried), but I'd like to keep all of my own code in `.vimrc`. I found another solution, which is to use `BufReadPre` instead of `BufRead`

Comment: Is the thought process to set the syntax in `BufReadPre` and then let Vim's normal `BufRead` clobber it?  I suppose that could work.  FWIW, if you're going to be a serious user of Vim, you'll want the `.vim` area.  You'll find that you're going to want to tweak some of the defaults, or do something a little extra and the `after` mechanism is really the only way to go. :-)

Comment: Yup, that's the logic! Your solution works so I have marked it as accepted. However, I think it is convenient to have all of my code in .vimrc when possible for easy portability (i.e. when I switch computers).

Comment: The other reason that it's nice to keep things in `.vim` folder is for easy version control without putting my entire home directory under version control.  To be honest, I've used the all-in-one vimrc, and having git involved to push and pull has been fantastic.  You can see my [`vimfiles`](https://github.com/jszakmeister/vimfiles) here, and there's a simple setup script to point your `.vimrc` to the right place.  I'm not trying to tear you away from your approach, just saying that keeping a `.vim` folder isn't as bad as it sounds. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[jszakmeister's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16011889/353278) diagnoses the problem accurately: `filetype.vim` sets the filetype for vimrc.

An alternative solution though, to keep everything contained in in your .vimrc file, is to use:

> au BufNewFile,BufReadPre * if &syntax == '' | silent! execute (':set filetype='.matchstr(resolve(@%),'.[^.]*$')[1:]) | endif

Note the change from **BufRead** to **BufReadPre**. The change causes this line to execute *before* filetype.vim. The syntax will be changed to `vimrc`, but then subsequently changed to `vim`. The upshot is that the script works as it should, but syntax highlighting for vimrc is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

When the current file is `~/.vimrc`, this part of your code

```
matchstr(resolve(@%),'.[^.]*$')
```

returns your file name: `.vimrc`.

I have no idea how you could imagine that `/home/username/.vimrc` would produce `vim`.

This is rather obviously a bad approach for the problem you tried to solve but there's no bug: you get exactly what you ask for. Using the filename/extension for filetype can't work reliably (`js` vs `javascript`, `py` vs `python`…).

You will probably need a filename/filetype list or many `if/elseif` if you want your code to do what you want.

See `:h syntax-loading`.

Comment: I think you've misread my question. *Without* that line in my .vimrc, `&syntax==vim`. So when I *add* that line to my .vimrc, why does the syntax change to `vimrc`? Shouldn't the `if &syntax == ''` evaluate to nil since `&syntax==vim`?

Comment: @Jeff, it changes to `vimrc` because you tell it to do so. The answer to your question is in `:h syntax-loading` (this pointer is in my answer): `syntax` is set on `BufReadPost` but your autocommand is triggered before, on `BufRead`. At that point, `syntax` is not set.